# Update ArrayAdapter with Firebase ChildEventListener()

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-arrayadapter

I have a Firebase db structured like so:

```
   {
  "reviews" : {
    "Star Trek Into Darkness" : {
      "j" : {
        "major" : "NONE",
        "rating" : 3.0,
        "username" : "j"
      }
    },
    "Star Wars" : {
      "badabing" : {
        "major" : "Computer Science",
        "rating" : 3.5,
        "username" : "badabing"
      },
      "j" : {
        "major" : "NONE",
        "rating" : 5.0,
        "username" : "j"
      }
    },
    "Star Wars: The Clone Wars" : {
      "j" : {
        "major" : "NONE",
        "rating" : 3.0,
        "username" : "j"
      }
    },
    "Star Wars: The Force Awakens" : {
      "badabing" : {
        "major" : "Computer Science",
        "rating" : 5.0,
        "username" : "badabing"
      },
      "j" : {
        "major" : "NONE",
        "rating" : 3.0,
        "username" : "j"
      }
    }
  }
```

There are movies under `reviews` and each `movie` has a `username`, `major`, and `rating`. I'm interested in getting those three children PER username (the parent of the three). What is supposed to be happening is when a user views the "Movie Details" screen of my app--they will see the reviews left by other users. Simple enough.

I'm having major difficulty with updating my custom `ReviewAdapter`. Currently, if we click on a movie that doesn't have a review--I can add them no problem. I can even submit an edit to the review I left. The only issue is that the submitted review submits two reviews--so I end up with a duplicate until I leave the activity and come back.

[My issue can be seen in this recording here. (No sound)](https://streamable.com/sm1r)

I suspect it has something to do with the way I'm using Firebase's `childEventListener()`, but I couldn't figure out what to change after spending 4hrs+ on this issue alone.

**MovieDetailActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            mMovieTitle = (String) bundle.get("title");
            mTempMovieTitle.setText(mMovieTitle);
        }

        setupReviews(); //calling it here
    }


public void leaveReview() {
        //get current username
        final String currentUser = SessionManager.getInstance(MovieDetailActivity.this).getLoggedInUsername();
        final MaterialDialog reviewDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MovieDetailActivity.this)
                .title(leaveReviewTitle)
                .customView(R.layout.rating_movie_dialog, true)
                .theme(Theme.DARK)
                .positiveText(save)
                .negativeText(cancel)
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog reviewDialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        final RatingBar ratingBar = ButterKnife.findById(reviewDialog, R.id.rating_bar);
                        final double rating = ratingBar.getRating(); //get the rating

                        /*Get Major from Firebase, and also store the review while we're at it*/
                        mUserRef.child(currentUser).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String major = dataSnapshot.child("major").getValue(String.class);
                                final Firebase reviewRef = mReviewRef.child(StringHelper.reviewHelper(mMovieTitle, currentUser));
                                reviewRef.child("username").setValue(currentUser);
                                reviewRef.child("major").setValue(major);
                                reviewRef.child("rating").setValue(rating);
                                setupReviews(); //and here
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).build();
        //Leave review as {current_username}
        TextView reviewee = ButterKnife.findById(reviewDialog, R.id.reviewee);
        reviewee.append(" " + (Html.fromHtml("<b>" + currentUser + "</b>"))); //bold the username text
        reviewDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * *ATTEMPTS* to add and update the reviews list per each movie. It's hacky and I hate it.
     */
    private void setupReviews() {
        mReviewRef.child(mMovieTitle).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
                ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> majors = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Double> ratings = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

                //iterate through all of the reviews for the movie
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    switch(child.getKey()) {
                        case ("username"):
                            usernames.add(child.getValue(String.class));
                            break;
                        case ("major"):
                            majors.add(child.getValue(String.class));
                            break;
                        case ("rating"):
                            ratings.add(child.getValue(Double.class));
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (!usernames.isEmpty()) { //only want to iterate if we're rating a movie that already has reviews
                    for (int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); ++i) {
                        try {
                            reviews.add(new Review(usernames.get(i), majors.get(i), ratings.get(i)));
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (mReviewAdapter == null) {
                    mReviewAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this,
                            R.layout.review_list_item, reviews);
                    mMovieReviewsList.setAdapter(mReviewAdapter);
                } else {
                    try {
                        mReviewAdapter.addAll(reviews);
                        mMovieReviewsList.setAdapter(mReviewAdapter);
                        mReviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
                ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> majors = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Double> ratings = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

                //iterate through all of the reviews for the movie
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    switch(child.getKey()) {
                        case ("username"):
                            usernames.add(child.getValue(String.class));
                            System.out.println("username " + child.getValue(String.class));
                            break;
                        case ("major"):
                            majors.add(child.getValue(String.class));
                            System.out.println("major " + child.getValue(String.class));
                            break;
                        case ("rating"):
                            ratings.add(child.getValue(Double.class));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (mReviewAdapter != null) {
                    mReviewAdapter.clear();
                }


                if (!usernames.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); ++i) {
                        try { //I hate that checking if Usernames != empty isn't enough, and this is
                            //the only way I could get it to work...
                            reviews.add(new Review(usernames.get(i), majors.get(i), ratings.get(i)));
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (mReviewAdapter == null) {
                    mReviewAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this,
                            R.layout.review_list_item, reviews);
                    mMovieReviewsList.setAdapter(mReviewAdapter);
                } else {
                    try {
                        mReviewAdapter.addAll(reviews); //this might break it
                        mMovieReviewsList.setAdapter(mReviewAdapter);
                        mReviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What video capture did you use here?

Comment: @Nxt3 Interesting video, may help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2J6spwAVP0M&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKkg55tSHz0Xc8ZMVS1GJQL&index=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use Push method for this to have their own Unique Key. You are using a key with the Username of the logged user. You need to do something like this.

```
    {
  "reviews" : {
    "Star Trek Into Darkness" : {
      "-K3dksosdfify" : {
        "major" : "NONE",
        "rating" : 3.0,
        "username" : "j"
      }
    },
    "Star Wars" : {
      "-K3dksosdfify2" : {
        "major" : "Computer Science",
        "rating" : 3.5,
        "username" : "badabing"
      },
      "-K3dksosdfify4" : {
        "major" : "NONE",
        "rating" : 5.0,
        "username" : "j"
      }
    },
    "Star Wars: The Clone Wars" : {
      "-K3dksosdfify10" : {
        "major" : "NONE",
        "rating" : 3.0,
        "username" : "j"
      }
    },
    "Star Wars: The Force Awakens" : {
      "-K3dksosdfify11" : {
        "major" : "Computer Science",
        "rating" : 5.0,
        "username" : "badabing"
      },
      "-K3dksosdfify123" : {
        "major" : "NONE",
        "rating" : 3.0,
        "username" : "j"
      }
    }
  }
```

The Dashes is FireBase Generated. [Check the push method in the Official Document](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html)

Now everytime you use push. It will generate a Unique key so The property of the other Rating will not be disturbed.

so something like this.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(yourURLtoReviews);
ref.child(SELECTEDMOVIES);

Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
post1.put("major", "gracehop");
post1.put("rating", "3.0");
post1.put("username", "Hwoarang");

ref.push().setValue(post1);
```

Now you don't need to care about the keys anymore. All you have to do is 
   ref.onChildAdded blah blah blah, itterate it with for loop and you're done.

Comment: I'm not having an issue with contamination of reviews--the issue is that there are duplicates added when submitting a review in the ListView--but when I leave and come back, all is fine. I don't see how `push()` solves anything--but that might be because I'm misunderstanding what it would do.

Comment: Hmm, let me review the code and check your video again.

Comment: Cause the way I see it, You're Updating the same thing? Do you want Multiple Ratings or No? If not, then You don't need Push. If yes, then you need push.

Comment: all you need is update when you don't want multiple addition to your List

Comment: A user submits one review per movie; they can, however, submit another review that would overwrite their current review. One review per movie per user.

Comment: Your edit doesn't fix the issue; it fixes it when I'm adding a new review--but if UserA has a review already published--and UserA submits another review for the same movie--both reviews will be displayed in the `ListView` until exiting and coming back to that Activity.

Comment: Yep, I saw your problem now. You're recreating everything in your List. Everytime there is an event. Either it is onchild added or onchildchange. 

You should fill your list from OnchildAdded. It will give you all of the items in Firebase at first run. Then onChildChange, You should not call your adapter anymore. Because it will change the value of your Data anyway.

Comment: So what should I call exactly? `mReviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't do anything.

Comment: You will need to change everything in your onChildchange. Because everything in there is Re-Creation of the List. You don't need to do that. All you have to do is Change the value in the Firebase and FireBase Listener will change the current list that you have.

Comment: OnChildChange is just one instance, you can't have many changes at a time, you don't need for loop for it. You will get one instance of it. Unless onChildChange is your first run in Firebase, which the rule is every first run returns a list.

Comment: First thing, You would need to Create a List of your Objects, Which is a Review. And I believe, you didn't create any Review Class for your FireBase. You would need it so you would know, where in the List you need to update but choosing the correct index for example. List<Review> review = new Review();

Now review[2].Rating = datasnapshot.getString("rating");

Comment: Okay--but it still isn't just updating the change. I edited my `onChildChanged()` to be only one line: `mReviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.  [This is what is happening now](https://streamable.com/g1mz).

Comment: Ofcourse it will do that. You're not changing anything. You're still adding. Your onclick method needs to know whether you already have added your reviews or not. Meaning, you would have to set your Firebase reference to your Key value which is your username and Instead of setting a whole new Object of reviews, you just have to setValue the Ratings. As easy as that.

Comment: Code-wise, I'm not sure I follow simply because you said I wouldn't have to loop anything. I'm pretty confused. :\ I understand what I need to do, but I'm unsure of the implementation.

Comment: Because I am trying to point you where you can fix your code and clean it up. For Just fixing. Just Create a List of your result from your FireBase, meaning Array if you don't know what a list is, Then onChildAdded. Loop the snapshots and add it to the Array. After looping, Call the adapter. Now when you call on ChildAdded. Clear the List and for loop the data snapshot and add again.<-- this is just to fix your problem but not best practice. Then call the Adapter.

Comment: The Array should be Instantiated in your Class on CreateView, not as a local member of the Method.